# Dynamically reading and writing to Excel sheets

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to create a new Excel file with multiple sheets (# sheets = # items in NameList). And then each sheet should be named with the corresponding entry from NameList. After this is done, I need a way of calling up each sheet.

The problems I've been having are: worksheets does not like to be set as a List and will not accept a variable in (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[variable]

I can write flawlessly to a single sheet, but any attempts to create a sheet have failed.

```
    public CreateExcelDoc excell_app { get; set; }
    public Excel.Workbook workbook { get; set; }
    public List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
    public List<Excel.Worksheet> worksheets { get; set; } // tried: = new List<Excel.Worksheet>();


    public void setupFile(int i) // this method errors on each of the 2 lines
            {
                worksheets[i] = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Add();
                worksheets[i].Name = NameList[i];
            } // this method is in a separate public class from CreateExcelDoc


        public class CreateExcelDoc
        {
            private Excel.Application app = null;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
            private Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;
            public CreateExcelDoc()
            {
                try
                {
                    app = new Excel.Application();
                    app.Visible = true;
                    workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
                    //worksheets[0] = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
                    //worksheet.Name = "t";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while exporting to Excel doc. Error: " + e.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }
    _Other Methods for writing to cells omitted_
    }
```

Comment: You say it "errors" - what errors do you see? Also, is there a reason you use a separate `List<Excel.Worksheet>` rather than just using the built-in `Worksheets` property?

Comment: NullReference is the specific error. This happens no matter what the variable is set to. --- What's the syntax for the `Worksheets` property? If I knew how to use it I might be able to do some experimenting. (Been programming for 21 years, but only 3 days with Excel hooks.)

Comment: Based on the rules and recommendations for using the `Excel` interface, I ended up using the OOXML SDK instead, so this is from the memory of doing that. That said, I think I found your issue. It appears you have two definitions of `workbook` - one is the property, and the other is the local variable, but I can't tell because of code formatting. Try cleaning up your code a bit?

Comment: I see the conflict you're talking about, but can't seem to remove it. I believe my error is in how I am referencing the workbook and worksheet variables, which are meant to be global.

Comment: @Tawnos Found where my problem was. The conflict you mentioned was a symptom/byproduct of it. I needed to put a subroutine method in my Excel class that modifies the sheets. Doing so from outside the class was not going to work. When I get it worked out I'll post my own answer. :P